# Проблема с запуском load balancer на aws через terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Коллеги, пытаюсь запустить терраформом 2 инстанса с балансировщиком нагрузки, но получаю ошибку:
"Error: "ASG-Web-server-20210525085155276300000001": Waiting up to 10m0s: Need at least 2 healthy instances in ELB, have 0"

Захожу через веб-морду в консоль AWS - вижу оба своих инстанса, прекрасно себя чувствующих, healthy.
Почему ELB то при этом считает, что с ними что-то не так?
Код main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  owners      = ["099720109477"]
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "web" {
  name = "Dynamic Security Group"

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = ["22", "80"]
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value
      to_port     = ingress.value
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name  = "Web access for Application"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "web" {
  name_prefix     = "Web-server-"
  image_id        = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type   = "t3.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.web.id]
  user_data       = file("user_data.sh")
  key_name = "laptop"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "web" {
  name                 = "ASG-${aws_launch_configuration.web.name}"
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.web.name
  min_size             = 2
  max_size             = 2
  min_elb_capacity     = 2
  health_check_type    = "ELB"
  vpc_zone_identifier  = [aws_default_subnet.availability_zone_1.id, aws_default_subnet.availability_zone_2.id]

  load_balancers       = [aws_elb.web.name]

  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = {
      Name   = "WebServer in Auto Scalling Group"
    }
    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }
  
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_elb" "web" {
  name               = "WebServer-Highly-Available-ELB"
  availability_zones = [data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0], data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]]
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.web.id]
  listener {
    lb_port           = 80
    lb_protocol       = "http"
    instance_port     = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
  }
  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 3
    target              = "HTTP:80/"
    interval            = 10
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "WebServer-Highly-Available-ELB"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "availability_zone_1" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "availability_zone_2" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
}

output "web_loadbalancer_url" {
  value = aws_elb.web.dns_name
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Comment: Что получаешь если в браузере откроешь health check url?

Comment: Судя по конфигу sg разрешает коннект на 80 порт, а health check path - /. То есть должно открываться хттп://ip-инстанса/ и возвращать код 200.

Comment: @MikhailP., получаю "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: @MikhailP., А хотя... Нет, это я туплю: если слэш добавить, то в ответ код 200 в консоли вижу.

Однако, я продолжаю тупить - что где в конфиге подправить надо, чтоб взлетело? :)

Comment: Видимо где-то в секции health_check->target, но сначала посмотри какой health check path в aws консоли, у этой target group, или где там этот путь задаётся. Порт тоже проверь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена: оказалось, что я, к своему стыду, забыл в скрипт, инициализирующийся при запуске инстансов, добавить команду установки и запуска nginx, поэтому 80 порт не открывался, поэтому при попытке через него проверить здоровье инстансов балансировщик не находил годных инстансов.